# Configure amazons3 to run WebAPI

Tags: angular, amazon-s3

I have created an seprate Web API to provide functionality to angular2 form. This API accepts the data and write into file. This works perfectly on the localhost.

How do I configure amazons3 to run this Web API sepretly ?

Reference: [Angular form service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45815232/angular-form-service)

Comment: Deploy it to beanstalk or use AWS code deploy.  Either way you'll need to install aws tool if you haven't done so already.

Comment: @RandomUs1r I am new to amazon services could you share some link which could guide me through above.

Comment: try... http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_NET.quickstart.html Past that, there's a ton of documentation on google for deploying to beanstalk.

Comment: @Neerajkumar, try to setup your api in aws api gateway and for processing use aws lambda function using which you can also write a file on S3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Neerajkumar, try to setup your api in aws api gateway and for processing use aws lambda function using which you can also write a file on S3.